# Avoid CMAKE linking against @rpath and use absolute paths instead

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, rpath

#### Build

I am building a CMAKE executable and link against an external library.

For the library I have a custom FindMYLIB cmake scribt that sucessfully sets `MYLIB_LIBRARIES` variable. promting

```
MESSAGE("${MYLIB_LIBRARIES}")
```

correctly yields

```
/usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib
```

I link my executable using

```
target_link_libraries(my_executable
        ${MYLIB_LIBRARIES}
        )
```

No custom settings in regards to `RPATH` are set anywhere in my toolchain or CMAKE code.

#### Problem

Running it gives me the error

```
dyld[94833]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libmylib.dylib
  Referenced from: <3747E824-3D4B-38A3-BFD8-E96891349DD5> /path/to/my_executable
  Reason: no LC_RPATH's found
```

Upon inspecting what is linked I read

```
$ otool -L /path/to/my_executable
/path/to/my_executable:
    ...
    @rpath/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    ...
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.151.0)
```

The following does NOT occur and IS MISSING

```
$ otool -l /path/to/my_executable
[...]
Load command NN
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path /usr/local/lib (offset 12)
```

#### Mitigation

I found out that the following fixes the executable by setting `LC_RPATH` explicitly:

```
install_name_tool -add_rpath /usr/local/lib /pyth/to/my_executable
```

#### Question

How do I avoid having a link against `@rpath` in the first place and use absolute paths instead? Since CMAKE is in possesion of absolute paths, how do they end up as relative links?

Building the same on another machine produceds only absolute paths.

#### Setup

Mac OSX, M1
cmake 3.23.2
AppleClang 15

#### Further Details

I have a symbolic link `libmylib.dylib -> libmylib-XX.YY.ZZ.dylib`

wheras the first is found in CMAKE and the second occurs as linked name.

#### Unsuccessful so far

several CMAKE flags, including `CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH`

### EDIT 1

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib")
```

makes the executable run.

It mitigates the issue of not having `/usr/local/lib` as rpath, but does not resolve my issue of rpaths being installed.

### EDIT 2

Minimal example

```
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(test_exe)

add_executable(test_exe main.cpp)

target_include_directories(test_exe
        PRIVATE /usr/local/include)

target_link_libraries(test_exe
        PRIVATE
        /usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib
        )
```

```
// main.cpp

#include <mylib/version.hxx>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Linker:

```
/usr/bin/c++
    -g
    -arch
    arm64
    -isysroot
    /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX14.0.sdk
    -Wl,-search_paths_first
    -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names

    CMakeFiles/test_exe.dir/main.cpp.o
    -o
    test_exe

    /usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib
```

```
$ otool -L ./cmake-build-debug/test_exe

    @rpath/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.151.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.0.0)
```

#### Edit 3

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib

    @rpath/libmylib.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.151.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.0.0)
```

So the library knows its own name as an rpath-stuff.

renaming its internal using

```
install_name_tool -id
    /usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib
```

to have it point to its absolute path resolves the issue in some cases.

My executable links against `/usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib` and finds it.

But it is still not runnable as several other .dylib are referenced by `libmylib.dylib`. I would have to hack all of these. The key issue here is I am unhappy with how my package provider (build2) is building the library.

Comment: As the very first step, do a verbose build and look at the link command as executed by `make`. Do you spot any problem in it?

Comment: The problem *could be* that `/usr/local/lib` is a place searched by the linker by default, but not by the runtime linker/loader. Because of that it is *not recommended* to install shared/dynamic libraries to `/usr/local/lib`. You either need to add `rpath` ro everything you build, or modify the system-wide dynamic loader config (no idea where it is on Mac OS, but on many systems it's in  `/etc/ld.so.conf`).

Comment: By default, for executables in the **build tree** CMake adds **absolute paths** for linked libraries in RPATH. When **installs** those executables, CMake **strips** those absolute paths from RPATH. This behavior is described e.g. here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling. So, which exact executable has unexpected RPATH, the one in the *build tree*, or the one in the *install tree*?

Comment: Well apparently Mac OS X is too different from everything else so my previous comment probably doesn't apply.

Comment: The shorted version of the verbose dump is the following:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
[...]
-Wl,-search_paths_first
-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names

[... all the cpp.o files]

-o
my_executable

-L/opt/homebrew/lib
-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib
-Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/lib
-Wl,-rpath,/opt/homebrew/opt/libomp/lib

[... other libs]
/usr/local/lib/libmylib.dylib
[...]

```

In my CMake I have 
```
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)
link_directories(/opt/homebrew/lib)
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/homebrew/")
```

Comment: @Tsyvarev Both. `otool -L [...]/cmake-build-debug/my_executable` yields identical output as the installed exe.

Comment: So it smells like your project actually sets some CMake variable which modifies RPATH-related behavior of CMake. Please, prepare [mcve]: the **complete code** but without unneeded complexity like `find_package`, presets and so on.

Comment: ATM we found out, that the library internally knows its name as `@rpath/...` so linking it will always fail...